# Typedef function pointer - differences between use & or not use it

Tags: c, typedef

Using typedef for functions, like in the following example, are there any differences between using the address of the function or only the function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int i){return i+1;}

typedef int(*mytype[2])(int);

int main(void)
{
    mytype f;

    f[0] = foo;
    f[1] = &foo;
    printf("%d %d", f[0](5), f[0](6));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See e.g. [this function to pointer conversion reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Function_to_pointer_conversion).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The reference seems incorrect. Surely, a function designator which is operand to the function call operator (`()`) also does not undergo conversion.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Are you sure? The postfix operator `()` expects a "pointer to function" as its operand in my version of the C standard.

Comment: @undur_gongor Interesting. You never stop learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C language, functions are implicitly converted to function pointers in most contexts. Thus you see no difference between `f[0] = foo` and `f[1] = &foo`. I prefer the latter convention, but really, both are equally fine.